# Groups with uniform bound on the order of conjugacy classes

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $G’$ is its derived subgroup constructed by commutators. It is easy to show that when $G’$ is finite, each conjugacy class is finite  and for each conjugacy class $C$, $|C|\leq |G’|$. As I have been advised, the converse is also true i.e. if 
$$
\sup_{C \in\  \text{conjugacy classes of $G$}} |C| <\infty,
$$
then $G’$ is finite. I am looking for a reference and naturally a proof for this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is proved in the beautiful paper, by B.H. Neumann, Groups covered by permutable subsets. J. London Math. Soc. 29, 236–248 (1954).  I cannot find an accessible copy online, but a proof can also be found in Robinson (*A Course in the theory of groups*), 14.5.11.

Comment: The proof is very beautiful and so non-trivial! Thanks.